# How to use ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags in custom class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby newbie here.

I create a class called My_table (without extend anything). I want to use ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags(text).

I put the following on the top of my class, but that doesn't work.

```
require 'rubygems'
gem rails
```

Comment: Is this outside of a rails app, ie you are making a simple ruby app from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested but what about something like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'action_controller'
puts ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags("<p>Testing</p>")
```

Obviously you need to have the rails gem installed first (`gem install rails` from the command line) but there shouldn't be any reference to `gem rails` in your ruby script.